# Prove $0$ is an exponentially stable equilibrium of the system $x'=f(x)+g(x)$ if $f(0)=g(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Besides the conditions in the title, we have:

1. $0$ is an exponential equilibrium of the system $y'=f(y)$
2. $|g(x)|\leq \mu|x|,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
3. $\mu$ is sufficiently small!

What I have tried so far is that:

1. $||y(0)||<\delta_1\Rightarrow ||y(t)||<\alpha_1||y(0)||e^{-\beta_1 t},t\geq0$
2. We want to prove: $\exists \delta,\alpha,\beta>0,$ such that $||x(0)||<\delta\Rightarrow ||x(t)||<\alpha||x(0)||e^{-\beta t},t\geq0$

Considering the following system:

1. $x_1'(t)=f(x_1)$
2. $x_2'(t)=g(x_2)$

Then we will have:

1. $\exists \alpha_1 ,\beta_1, \delta>0$ such that $||x_1(0)||<\delta_1\Rightarrow ||x_1(t)||<\alpha_1||x_1(0)||e^{-\beta_1 t},t\geq0$
2. $x_2'(t)\leq \mu|x_2(t)|$, and by Gronwall inequality $x_2(t)\leq x_2(0)e^{\mu t}$

I have a sense that it might be somewhat close to what we want to get. And I am stuck at this stage.

I would really appreciate any suggestion to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) = -\frac12\mu x$, then the equation $y' = f(y)$ has $0$ as an exponentially stable fixed point.  Now consider $g(x) = \mu x$.  Then $x' = f(x) + g(x) = \frac12 \mu x$ has $0$ as an unstable fixed point.  What am I missing?

Comment: Auch, I forgot to mention a seemingly trivial condition in the question "$\mu$ is sufficiently small", which I think it's not trivial now.

Comment: You mean, $\mu$ is chosen sufficiently small, and the choice of $\mu$ depends upon the choice of $f$?

Comment: I am not sure but I think we can choose whatever the way we want to make $\mu$ small, i.e., dependent on the choice of $f$, since the question doesn't make any restriction on this. But what is you intention of making this dependence?

Comment: What assumptions do we have on $f$ and $g$?  Are they smooth functions?

Comment: Personally, I think our professor didn't really make the question very rigorous. For simplicity, let's just temporarily say $f,g$ are smooth enough (even infinitely differentiable) and see if we can make the conclusion of the question. (There is even an interesting comment in the question “The moral of this exercise is that exponential stability is robust”)

Comment: now I might see what you are trying: $x_2\leq x_2(0)\cdot e^{\mu t}$ can be assumed as $x_2\leq x_2(0)\cdot\epsilon e^{-\beta t}$ if $\mu$ is sufficiently small as we wish

Comment: I think you are meant to use the characterization that $0$ is exponentially stable if the eigenvalues of the derivative matrix of $f$ at $x=0$ all have real part strictly less than zero.  And the condition upon $g$ implies that the derivative matrix of $g$ has all its singular values bounded by $\mu$.  Thus you have to prove that given a matrix whose real parts of eigenvalues are bounded above by a given negative number, that if you add to it another matrix whose singular are sufficiently small, then the new matrix thus obtain will still have that same property.

Comment: I'm reading Edgar Allen Poe to my son, who has homework due tomorrow.  Perhaps that is why my previous comment is in such a long winded, and perhaps hard to discern, style.

Comment: Anyway, I can't do much more tonight.  But tomorrow, or soon after, as time allows, I shall try to answer your further questions, if they arise.

Comment: Haha, math combined with poetry. That's cool! Your answer is indeed really helpful, and I think I can figure out the rest! And again, thanks for your help!